# focalMat weights adjustment

Tags: r, focal-statistics, terra

I'm trying to calculate a spatially weighted focal function using `terra::focal()` and `focalMat()`.

```
library(terra)

r <- rast(ncols=10, nrows=10, ext(0, 10, 0, 10))
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)

w <- focalMat(r,  d = 1, type = 'Gauss')
```

The values of w sum to 1, so when I try

```
q99 <- focal(r, w, fun = function(i) {quantile(i, 0.99, na.rm = TRUE)})
```

the values in the output raster are not in the range I'd expect for a set of local 99th percentile values. I think what I need is a weighting matrix where the values are close to 1 in the centre and close to 0 at the edges. What's the easiest way to either generate one of those from scratch in R or modify what `focalMat()` produces?

Comment: I'm a bit concerned about what this actually is computing. A weighted median (the 50% percentile) isn't just the median of the values times the weights, so I think the same applied for any percentile. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_median

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide `w` by its maximum value to scale it linearly between small values and 1.

```
w = w/max(w)
image(w)
filled.contour(w)
```

`filled.contour` does some funky smoothing on display, `image` is true to the data but there's no legend. Other matrix display functions are available.

Comment: i have learned more than one thing today, many thanks!